# How can i make presences loop?

Tags: python, discord

How can i make presences loop? I want it to change presence every 5-10 sec.

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or(","))

async def presenced():
    presences = ["Prefix: ,", "Over people!"]
    activity = discord.Activity(
        name=random.choice(presences), type=discord.ActivityType.watching)
    await client.change_presence(activity=activity)

client.loop.create_task(presenced())
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267705/making-a-discord-bot-change-playing-status-every-10-seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't already find an answer I got something that should work.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import random


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or(","))

async def on_ready():
    print("client is online!") # you can add other things to this on_ready listener
    client.loop.create_task(presenced()) # start the presenced task when the bot is ready

client.add_listener(on_ready)

async def presenced():
    while True:
        presences = ["Prefix: ,", "Over people!"]
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(name=random.choice(presences), type=discord.ActivityType.watching))
        await asyncio.sleep(10) # you can of course add some randomizer to this delay




client.run("bot token here :)")
```