# Do an if statement after while loop discord.py

Tags: python, loops, discord, discord.py

```
import ...
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

  counter = 0
  trigger = True

  while trigger:
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    counter += 1

  if message.content.startswith('count'): await message.channel.send(counter)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')
    
client.run(TOKEN)
```

I am trying to do a while loop.

the loop works but when I message count to see the counter, the message doesn't come out. if i place the
if statement before the loop it will say 0

please help me

Comment: Your loop never ends because `trigger` is always `True`. Is there any code that is supposed to change the value of `trigger`?

Comment: i didn't expect it to be so quick, thx

Comment: but i wanted the loop to not end so...

Comment: You need to put your `if` statement in the loop. The indentation is important in Python so you have to have the same indentation for your `if` statement than your `count += 1` statement.

Comment: Can you explain what the loop is supposed to achieve? Because the way it's currently written, the line `if message.content.startswith(...)` is never reached.

Comment: I wanted it so that every 5 seconds the  counter increases by 1

Comment: @MetallimaX It works but the bot spams it

Comment: So you want the bot to tell the current count in chat when a message with `"count"` arrives, and the count should increase independently of that by 1 every 5 seconds?

Comment: @Tomalak yes...

Comment: Then it would be logical that "increasing the count" should not be a part of the `on_message` event, because you want the count to increase *independently of incoming messages*. What happens when you move the loop to the `on_ready` event? (because you want the bot to start counting when it's ready)

Comment: @Tomalak the if statement didn't work

Comment: Have a look at how background tasks can be created: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46267969/18771. This is a perfect fit for a task like "increase a counter every 5 seconds". Define a global variable `bot_state = {"counter": 0}` and set `bot_state["counter"] += 1` in the task.

Comment: Where do i place the if statement?

Comment: File "main.py", line 260, in on_ready
    bot.loop.create_task(status_task())
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined

Comment: @Tomalak I cant acces the counter in the if statement

Comment: You're not supposed to copy single lines of code from the other answer without understanding them. Of course that won't work. You are supposed to read the other answer, understand what it means, look up the relevant parts of the documentation, read and understand *that*, and then write *your own code* that follows the same principles.

Comment: @Tomalak I have been searching and trying for three hours, I cant find an answer. idk why but i cant import commands from discord.ext

Comment: I have found the way, thankd

Answer (score 0):

```
async def token():
  global counter
  counter = 0
  while True:
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    counter += 1

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

  if message.content.startswith('check'):
    await message.channel.send(counter)

client.loop.create_task(token())
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: @borchvm Thx I will