# rotating status and command usage

Tags: python, discord.py

so, im trying to make a multiple status for my discord bot, but i cant find anything.

also im trying to make the status show how many times two commands have been used globally

this is what ive tried for multiple status

````
async def change_playing():
    threading.Timer(10, change_playing).start()
    await test_bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Currently on ' + str(len(client.servers)) +
                                                          ' servers'))
    threading.Timer(10, change_playing).start()
    await test_bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Say shelp'))```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a discord bot change playing status every 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267705/making-a-discord-bot-change-playing-status-every-10-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

i found it, but thanks for the help

````
  guilds = len(client.guilds)
  users = len(client.users)
  await client.wait_until_ready()
  statuses = ["Shelp", f"im in {guilds} guilds| watching {users} users", "with knives"]
  while True:
    game = discord.Game(random.choice(statuses))
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status, activity=game)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
  
client.loop.create_task(roll_presence())```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
#fixed one

 1. List item

import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

SAYHELP = discord.Game(name="Say shelp")
SERVER_COUNT = discord.Game(name=f'Currently on {len(client.servers)} servers'))
   

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def change_playing():
    if test_bot.activity is SAYHELP:
        await test_bot.change_presence(game=SERVER_COUNT)
    else:
        await test_bot.change_presence(game=SAYHELP)

 1. List item

async def on_ready(self, *args, **kwargs):

    change_playing.start()
    super().__on_ready__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add this to your bot with the `discord.ext.tasks` decorator that was made for the very purpose of repeating an action every n seconds.
The docs for it are [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html).

You could do something like

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

SAYHELP = discord.Game(name="Say shelp")
SERVER_COUNT = discord.Game(name=f'Currently on {len(client.servers)} servers'))

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def change_playing():
    if test_bot.activity is SAYHELP:
        test_bot.change_presence(game=SERVER_COUNT)
    else
        test_bot.change_presence(game=SAYHELP)

async def on_ready(self, *args, **kwargs):
    change_playing.start()
    super().__on_ready__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Just don't forget to update the `SERVER_COUNT` activity whenever the bot gets added to another server. There's [this event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_guild_join) that gets fired then.

As for the command usage counter, there's a couple approaches to this that depend entirely on how you're instantiating your bot.
If you're just using the `discord.ext.commands.Bot` class as-is, you'll want to define an integer for that in your top-level code and increment that every time the relevant command is called.
If you're subclassing the bot, however, then you can define `self.commandcounter` in your bot and have the commands update that instead.
If you're also using cogs, then make sure the cog has a reference back to the bot so you can increment `self.bot.commandcounter`.

You could then have the `@task` decorated function set that as presence as well. Might need to add another check for the current activity though.

The [docs for dpy](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) are a good place to start looking if you can't get something to work.

Comment: alr, do you know anything about the usage counter?

Comment: You'd store that in some globally accessible bot data and format it into the string much like how you'd do it for `len(client.servers)`. Which I'll edit into the answer

Comment: also the provided code, didnt work, no status is showing

Comment: Riven didn't mention it but you need to start the loop via `change_playing.start()`, which can be done in an `on_ready` event. Riven also didn't mention that changing your status every 10 seconds is going to ratelimit your bot, so I'd recommend at least 10 minutes per status change.

Comment: I'd figured the missing `start()` call would be easily solved when reading the documentation, which I linked because they _clearly_ explain how to do this...
As for a testing bot, that shouldn't be performing enough active requests to get ratelimited on 6 calls/min + command testing.